# How to multiply and divide Measurements

Tags: swift, product, foundation, divide, measurement

`Foundation.Measurement` seems great. How do I use it to do calculations?

```swift
import Foundation

let mass = Measurement(value: 1, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)
let length = Measurement(value: 1, unit: UnitLength.meters)
let duration = Measurement(value: 1, unit: UnitDuration.seconds)

let force = mass * length / duration * duration
```

The above code doesn’t work:

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Measurement' and 'Measurement'

Where would I start to make this possible?

Comment: Thanks for this question, `Whal1978`.  I'm a little (actually, a lot) disappointed in Swift that this isn't supported out of the box, automatic tracking of units would be *extremely* helpful for many applications, and all the building blocks for it are already there.  I very often want to multiply `kW` by a time quantity and get `kWh`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

`Mass` , `Length` and `Duration` are of type `Measurement<UnitMass>`. You can't use directly `*` operator on them. You should access them by their `value`. Replace last line with following.

```
let force = mass.value * length.value / (duration.value * duration.value)
```

Comment: Nope.  That won't do it.

Comment: I ran it myself, It worked and only then I posted the answer!

Comment: Thanks, I’d like to find a solution where I can actually use `mass * length`

Comment: @Whal1978, If you are satisfied by the answer, Kindly accept!

Comment: @Coder I am not, I’d like to find a solution where I can actually use `mass * length`

Comment: @Whal1978 multiplying dimensions of different units doesn't come out of the box and you'd need to code it, including creating a custom dimension of Force (if that's what you think you'd need) and/or implementing operator overloads of `*` and `/` for the units that you care about. So you have multiple possible questions in one. This isn't a site for others to code for you. So, you'd need to try to code it yourself, and by all means, if you'd run into other issues, ask specific questions and we'll try to help. Here's a [blog](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/07/measurements-and-units/) to get started

Comment: @Whal1978, practically you can use `Measurement` to make apps like unit converters

Comment: @NewDev If I had asked others to code for me, I had asked for it. Instead I asked “Where would I start to make this possible?”. A question you answered Thanks for that.